# pull subdocument in array mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

i have in mongodb this structure

```
{doc:
    { array_doc:[....//many documents]}
}
```

im using mongoskin in mongodb 2.2 with nodejs 0.8

```
var code_doc='HSKD41814541211';
var db = mongo.db(perm+"@127.0.0.1:27017/database",{safe:true});
    db.collection('comercio').findAndModify(
    {
        'code':code,
        'email':email,
    },[],{$pull:{'doc.array_doc':{'doc.array_doc.code_doc':code_doc}}},{new:true},function(err,result)
```

i want to erase a document from array_doc array that have many documents inside, each document inside the array have a unique code_doc... i want to erase the document that match with the variable code_doc='HSKD41814541211';

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't replicate your key in the value being pulled.  Your `$pull` operator should look like this instead:

```
{$pull: {'doc.array_doc': {code_doc: code_doc}}}
```